# How to run non-Java tests within maven-failsafe?

Tags: integration-testing, exec-maven-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

I am building a webapp project using Maven, using maven-failsafe-plugin for my integration tests. A cargo Glassfish3x container is started bound to the pre-integration-test phase, and stopped as part of the post-integration-test phase.

However, my integration tests are in a pyUnit based script.
I tried running them both using exec-maven-plugin, and using nosetests/freshen through maven-bdd-plugin.

Both methods run the script fine, but if the tests fail, they fail the Maven build immediately. Maven does not run the post-integration-test phase, leaving a running cargo container behind, which fails any other attempts to run the tests.

How can I configure maven-failsafe to interpret my failing exec to be a failing test, so that it does its job and runs the post-integration-test phase?

Comment: I know it is very old question, but I have very same problem. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it answers your question but: we resigned from this approach. we had similar situation: maven backend and angular frontend. theoretically it is probably possible but this integration never will be as good as native support for java or python tools. and you should always use best tool for the job. so why limit yourself? why do you want foreign tests being run by maven? your CI server can fire 2 different jobs. if you have one-click full tests on your dev machine then create shell script - will be way easier